# Ошибка в NetBeans ' ' СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 229ms) ' '

Tags: c++, netbeans, linux-mint

Здравствуйте не могу собрать программу, ошибка:

> ```
> cd '/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
> /usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
> "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
> make[1]: вход в каталог «/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1»
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:78: предупреждение: переопределение способа для цели «build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o»
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:73: предупреждение: старый способ для цели «build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o» игнорируются
> "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_1
> make[2]: вход в каталог «/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1»
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:78: предупреждение: переопределение способа для цели «build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o»
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:73: предупреждение: старый способ для цели «build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o» игнорируются
> mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
> g++-5     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o 
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o: In function `main':
> /home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/newfile.cpp:3: multiple definition of `main'
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o:/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/main.cpp:21: first defined here
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux/newfile.o: In function `main':
> /home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/newfile.cpp:3: multiple definition of `main'
> build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o:/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/main.cpp:21: first defined here
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:64: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_1»
> make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication_1] Ошибка 1
> make[2]: выход из каталога «/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1»
> nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:61: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «.build-conf»
> make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Ошибка 2
> make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1»
> nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «.build-impl»
> make: *** [.build-impl] Ошибка 2
>
> СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 229ms)
> ```

Где мне можно найти документацию или как это понять? Подскажите, пожалуйста, я нечего не знаю. Я новичок и я не знаю программирования. У меня linux mint, среда NetBeans.

Comment: Приведите листинг newfile.cpp и main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

У вас функция `main` два раза определена. Один раз в 'newfile.cpp', другой в `main.cpp`. Функция `main` это точка входа в программу с нее наичнается ее выполнение. Поэтому она должна быть определена только один раз.